# port redirect with vpn

Tags: linux, iptables

pc1 is a client inside lan with openvpn ip 10.8.0.1

/sbin/ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:09:D0:08:99:15  
          inet addr:192.168.2.130  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9209:d0ff:fe08:9915/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:206125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:206479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:68902617 (65.7 MiB)  TX bytes:49582255 (47.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:11 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:277005 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:277005 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:38573288 (36.7 MiB)  TX bytes:38573288 (36.7 MiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3075 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:300198 (293.1 KiB)  TX bytes:2344684 (2.2 MiB)
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.100   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i tun0 --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.100:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.100 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

inside this lan there is another client on eth0: 192.168.2.100

from another vpn client on other side ip: 10.8.0.2 I need to connect to port 80 of 192.168.2.100

timeout